# Consolidating event listeners and click handlers

Tags: javascript

I have a script which toggles the display of content from two divs. I'm currently using one event listner and one click handler on each of the links, but need to consolidate them into one. In the end, there should be one click handler that looks for the id (`en` or `de`) based on the clicked link and toggles the view based on that, rather than the below implementation. I'm a bit stuck on how I can use one to look for the id of either link and toggle based on that.

```js
const Terms = {
  bindEvents () {
    this.enTrigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.langToggle(this.englishContent)
      this.enTrigger.classList.add('active')
      this.frTrigger.classList.remove('active')
    })
    this.frTrigger.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      this.langToggle(this.frenchContent)
      this.frTrigger.classList.add('active')
      this.enTrigger.classList.remove('active')
    })
  },

  init () {
    this.englishContent = document.getElementById('english-terms')
    this.frenchContent = document.getElementById('french-terms')
    this.enTrigger = document.getElementById('en')
    this.frTrigger = document.getElementById('fr')
    this.bindEvents()
  },

  langToggle (id) {
    this.englishContent.style.display = 'none'
    this.frenchContent.style.display = 'none'
    id.style.display = 'block'
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  Terms.init()
})
```

```css
.trigger.active {color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="terms-nav">
  <a class="trigger active" id="en">English</a>
  <a class="trigger" id="fr">French</a>
</div>
<div id="english-terms">English Content</div>
<div id="french-terms" style="display:none">French Content</div>
```

Comment: Hi Matt, have you achieved something? I would like to have a bit of feedback on my answer

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález - I see what you did with your solution, thanks. I do wonder if there's a simpler solution than having to loop through the languages on every click, but this should work.

Comment: Well, you can do it like you have done until now. By accessing one by one and check if is the one clicked or not. The loop is in case that you have 10 languages, you don't have to hide and show each one of the languages, but just add them to the main object and forget about duplicated code. The result is the same, but avoiding duplicated code is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You said it. You create one listener and check for the id:

```js
const Terms = {
  bindEvents () {
    var listener = (e) => {
      var id = e.target.id; // Get the id of the element that was clicked
      if (id && this.buttons.hasOwnProperty(id)) { // Check if an element was actually selected
        this.buttons[id].classList.add('active');
        for (var i in this.buttons) { // Loop through the other elements and disable them (only one but to optimize if you add more).
          if (i != id) {
              this.buttons[i].classList.remove('active');
          }
        }
        this.langToggle(id);
      }
    };
    var languages = document.getElementById("terms-nav");
    languages.addEventListener("click", listener);
  },

  init () {
    this.buttons = {
      en: document.getElementById('en'),
      fr: document.getElementById('fr')
    };
    this.terms = {
      en: document.getElementById('english-terms'),
      fr: document.getElementById('french-terms')
    };
    this.bindEvents();
  },

  langToggle (id) {
    for (var i in this.terms) {
      if (i != id) {
        this.terms[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    this.terms[id].style.display = "block";
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  Terms.init()
})
```

```css
.trigger.active {color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="terms-nav" id="terms-nav">
  <a class="trigger active" id="en">English</a>
  <a class="trigger" id="fr">French</a>
</div>
<div id="english-terms">English Content</div>
<div id="french-terms" style="display:none">French Content</div>
```

And with this, you can also attach the listener only to the parent (is better to have only one event handler instead of 2 or more), and it will handle when the children are clicked.